# How to ommit codecheck when executing custom gradle task

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dsl

I have a gradle project which is building an api (KotlinPoet generating classes) by analyzing the local filesystem.

This is done by a custom gradle plugin.
The main application from the project then uses to pack and deploy the api.
Basically I want to utilize gradle to configure the distribution by a DSL.

One Gradle Task is to clean my buildDir/generated/classes.

This task must not check for errors of unresolved references within the generated code and I would like to know how to configure this task to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle provides base class for deletion tasks ([Delete](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html)) - use it:

```kotlin
tasks.register<Delete>("deleteGeneratedClasses") {
    delete("$buildDir/generated/classes")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I'm pretty sure to head towards the right direction because of your help.
However it does not the trick since, executing this task, it is still dependent on task "kotlinCompile".

I have to manually delete the generated folder, then classes will be (re)generated.

Please have a look to the screenshots.

While executing clean task: https://postimg.cc/K1RVW8JS

While executing kotlinCompile task explicitly and for demonstration purpose (don't care about the error): https://postimg.cc/ph43Q9wL

Comment: This task doesn't depend on anything. And not `compileKotlin` task is triggered in your case, but `buildSrc:compileKotlin`. This is unrelated to the deletion task. It happens by default if you have `buildSrc` directory in your project: _upon discovery of the directory, Gradle automatically compiles and tests this code and puts it in the classpath of your build script_ (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I suspected that behavior when working in that special case.
Good eyes, to identify where the phenomenons happen!